# Expected value of the exponential of a stopping time

Tags: stochastic-processes, expected-value, brownian-motion, martingales, stopping-times

#### Problem

> Let $a>0$ and $B$ be a standard $\mathbb{R}$-valued Brownian motion. Define the stopping time $S_a:=\inf\{t\geq 0\ \vert \left\lvert B_t\right\rvert = a\}$. Compute $\mathbb{E}\left[e^{-\frac{\lambda^2}{2}S_a}\right]$ for $\lambda\in\mathbb{R}$.

#### My (edited) attempt

I noticed that the expression I needed to compute looks similiar to the martingale $Z=(e^{\lambda B_t - \frac{1}{2}\lambda^2t})_{t\geq 0}$. Consider the bounded stopping time $S_a \land n\leq n$ for some $n\in\mathbb{N}$. Doob’s optional sampling theorem yields:

\begin{align*}
 \mathbb{E}\left[Z_{S_a\land n}\right] = \mathbb{E}\left[Z_0\right] = \mathbb{E}\left[e^{\lambda B_0 - \frac{1}{2}\lambda^20}\right] = 1\ \text{(a.s.)}
\end{align*}

We now have $\lim_{n\to\infty} Z_{S_a\land n} = Z_{S_a}$ (a.s.) and: $$\left\lvert Z_{S_a\land n}\right\rvert = e^{\lambda B_{S_a\land n} - \frac{1}{2}\lambda^2\left(S_a\land n\right)} \leq e^{\lambda B_{S_a\land n}} \leq e^{\left\lvert \lambda a\right\rvert}\ \text{(a.s.)}$$

Lebesgue’s dominated convergence theorem yields: $$\mathbb{E}\left[Z_{S_a}\right] = \mathbb{E}\left[\lim_{n\to\infty} Z_{S_a\land n}\right] = \lim_{n\to\infty} \mathbb{E}\left[Z_{S_a\land n}\right] = \lim_{n\to\infty} 1 = 1\ \text{(a.s.)}$$

Because of symmetry we have:
$$x:=\mathbb{E}\left[e^{-\frac{\lambda^2}{2}S_a}1_{\left\{B_{S_a}=a\right\}}\right]=\mathbb{E}\left[e^{-\frac{\lambda^2}{2}S_a}1_{\left\{B_{S_a}=-a\right\}}\right]\quad \text{(a.s.)}$$
$$\mathbb{E}\left[e^{-\frac{\lambda^2}{2}S_a}\right] = \mathbb{E}\left[e^{-\frac{\lambda^2}{2}S_a}1_{\left\{B_{S_a}=a\right\}}\right]+\mathbb{E}\left[e^{-\frac{\lambda^2}{2}S_a}1_{\left\{B_{S_a}=-a\right\}}\right] = 2x\quad \text{(a.s.)}$$
$x$ can now be computed through the first equation:
\begin{align*}
1 =\ &\mathbb{E}\left[e^{\lambda B_{S_a} - \frac{1}{2}\lambda^2S_a}\right]\\
=\ &\mathbb{E}\left[e^{\lambda B_{S_a} - \frac{1}{2}\lambda^2S_a} 1_{\left\{B_{S_a}=a\right\}}\right] + \mathbb{E}\left[e^{\lambda B_{S_a} - \frac{1}{2}\lambda^2S_a} 1_{\left\{B_{S_a}=-a\right\}}\right]\\
=\ &\mathbb{E}\left[e^{\lambda a - \frac{1}{2}\lambda^2S_a} 1_{\left\{B_{S_a}=a\right\}}\right] + \mathbb{E}\left[e^{-\lambda a - \frac{1}{2}\lambda^2S_a} 1_{\left\{B_{S_a}=-a\right\}}\right]\\
=\ &e^{\lambda a}\mathbb{E}\left[e^{-\frac{1}{2}\lambda^2S_a} 1_{\left\{B_{S_a}=a\right\}}\right] + e^{-\lambda a}\mathbb{E}\left[e^{- \frac{1}{2}\lambda^2S_a} 1_{\left\{B_{S_a}=-a\right\}}\right]\\
=\ &e^{\lambda a}x + e^{-\lambda a} x\\
=\ &\left(e^{\lambda a} + e^{-\lambda a}\right) x\quad \text{(a.s.)}
\end{align*}
The result is therefore:
$$\mathbb{E}\left[e^{-\frac{\lambda^2}{2}S_a}\right] = \frac{2}{e^{\lambda a} + e^{-\lambda a}}\quad \text{(a.s.)} $$

#### Questions

1. I am not very comfortable with how the result looks. Is my proof correct?
2. I feel like I used a trick to obtain the result. Is there a more general way to make this computation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All good. Perhaps, you can add more details on the "by symmetry" [Independence of $T$ and $B_T$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/404819/independence-of-t-and-b-t?rq=1) i.e. we have $B_t\stackrel{d}{=}-B_{t}$ and $S_{a}$ is only a function of $|B_{t}|$, which is symmetric already.

One can also use pde methods to find the law for the exit time [double barrier stopping time density function](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2322830/double-barrier-stopping-time-density-function).

Here is also the more general formula for exit time from (a,b) [Distribution of first exit time of Brownian motion](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3550228/distribution-of-first-exit-time-of-brownian-motion), where symmetry doesn't apply and instead one has to use the strong Markov property.

Comment: I noticed that I made use of Doob’s optional sampling theorem in a non-trivial way. I added some details and would greatly appreciate some feedback.

Comment: @WilfredMontoya yes that's good. You indeed need an integrable bound to apply optional.